# false proof that normality is hereditary

Tags: general-topology

I am using the following definition of normality : Given a closed set $F\subset V$, with $V$ open in $X$, there is an open set $U$ such that $F\subset U\subset \overline{U}\subset V$. I know that normality is not a hereditary property, so what is the problem with the following reasoning :

Let $X$ be a normal space and $A\subset X$ a subspace. Let $F$ be a closed set of $A$, so $F=F_1\cap A$, with $F_1$ closed set of $X$. Let $U$ be open set of $A$ such that $F\subset U$, with $U=U_1\cap A$ where $U_1$ is open in $X$.
Then, $F_1\cap A\subset U_1\cap A$ which implies $F_1\subset U_1$. Since $X$ is normal, there is an open set $V$ in $X$ such that $F_1\subset V\subset \overline{V}\subset U_1$. Let $W=V\cap A$, an open set in $A$ and let $\overline{W}$ denote its closure in $X$ and $\overline{W}^{A}$ its closure in $A$. One has that:
$F\subset W$ and that $\overline{W}^{A}=\overline{V\cap A}^{A}=A\cap\overline{V\cap A}\subset A\cap\overline{V}\cap\overline{A}=\overline{V}\cap A\subset U_1\cap A = U$.

Where exactly is the mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is: It is not true in general that $F_1 \subseteq U_1$, you cannot infer that from $F_1 \cap A \subseteq U_1 \cap A$.

Comment: true. silly mistake. thanks